# How to avoid argument-order dependencies in statically typed languages like Java or C#

Tags: java, c#

I'm from Python, Ruby and PHP world and one of techniques that I try to follow is removing argument-order dependencies from my code. This is a short demonstration of this technique implemented in Ruby:

```
class Gear
    attr_reader :chainring, :cog, :wheel
    def initialize(args)
       @chainring = args[:chainring]
       @cog = args[:cog]
       @wheel = args[:wheel]
    end
    ...
end

Gear.new(
   :chainring => 52,
   :cog => 11,
   :wheel => Wheel.new(26, 1.5)).gear_inches
```

As you can see the client code does not need to know the order of arguments for initializing a Gear instance and I like that. But now I just wonder how the same thing is implemented in statically typed languages like Java and I also wonder whether people try to follow such techniques or not in this kind of languages. If someone can share their experience and show some demo-code (let it be in Java, C# etc.), that would be great.

Comment: Probably, Facade pattern is used instead to simplify the client side?

Comment: You generally don't; you can use custom object instance(s) as your parameters (at least in Java, your argument order is part of the method signature).

Comment: It sounds like you may be interested in Groovy; it provides both named initializers and some other sugar you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is only for creating new object, you can use [Object Initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) :

```
public class Gear
{
    public int Chainring { get; set; }
    public int Cog { get; set; }
    public int Wheel { get; set; }
}

// ...
var gear = new Gear
{
    // could be in any order, 
    Cog = 11,
    Chainring = 52,
}
```

As for method arguments, check out KSid's answer on [Named and Optional Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37201240/561113).

Comment: Ah I think I misunderstood what the person asked, but I believe your answer is right.

Comment: @KSib Not at all, you covered for the 2nd case, but not totally.

Comment: I just spent ~10 minutes researching if `var` was a keyword in newer versions of Java. I forgot the question asked about C# as well. *facepalm*

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to adhere to an argument order in C#. If you know the parameter name you can take advantage of [named and optional arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) by using the parameter name, a colon and your value.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var variable1 = "1";
        var variable2= 90056;
        var variable3 = 'u';

        // random order
        TestMethod(arg3: variable3, arg1: variable1, arg2: variable2);

        // you can even omit some argument
        TestMethod(arg2: variable2);
    }

    private static void TestMethod(string arg1 = null, int arg2 = 0, char arg3 = '\0')
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg1);
        Console.WriteLine(arg2);
        Console.WriteLine(arg3);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I believe that Xiaoy312's answer is what you're looking for, but I'll leave this here just in case someone is curious about it later.

Comment: Expanded your answer, with optional arguments for completeness. I also changed the argument order to the way I like xP

Comment: Haha thats fine. Thanks for the assist either way :)

Answer (score 2):

That's a language feature that's present in some, but not all statically-typed languages. The feature is not present in Java, but it's present in Scala and it's present in C# (see KSib's answer).

Regarding your technique, there are a couple benefits.

1. Your code works even when argument order is changed
2. Improved compiler safety by being explicit about your parameters (e.g. compiler error if argument doesn't exist)
3. Improved readability where there are multiple overloads for a method
4. Improved readability/maintainability where there are multiple arguments of the same type

The downsides are

1. You're coupled to argument names
2. Argument names are more likely to change across minor revisions, but argument order is not supposed to change across minor revisions
3. More verbose code

Answer (score 2):

Try [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html).

In Java, argument order in methods is very much mandatory unless you are talking about command line applications and for that I would suggest using [Apache CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/). If you are talking about constructors, then Lombok is a good library for you. It implements a builder pattern and you can then create your instances based on any number of private variables you have declared and on any order you desire.

Say you have:

```
@Builder
public class MySuperClasse {

private int mySuperInt;

private String mySuperString;

private Date mySuperDate;

}
```

You can then build your instances like this:

```
MySuperClass super = MySuperClass.builder().mySuperString(string).mySuperInt(int).mySuperDate(date).build();
```

or you can do

```
MySuperClass super = MySupeClass.builder().mySuperDate(date).build();
```

Essentially what is happening is that when you annotate your class with @Builder, Lombok implicitly creates the builder and the different methods to create your instance. The beauty of it is that it does exactly what you want, however in a slighty different way.

Comment: Looks handy. Though, C# setters and getters seem more convenient.